# Volume of a solid about the y-axis

Tags: calculus, volume

I am new here, so please forgive any math formatting that is not up to spec.

I have the following problem that I need help with:
"Find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region bounded by the given lines and curves about the x-axis.

$y=x^2, y=0, x=0, x=3$

There are 4 answers on this problem:

1. $(81\div4)*\pi$
2. $9\pi$
3. $(243\div4)*\pi$
4. $(243\div5)*\pi$

I know that to find the volume, we need to integrate these x/y values.

$$\int_0^3 \pi x(x^2-0)dx $$

Then we take the anti-derivative:

$$ \pi x^4\div4$$

Then we calculate this over the integral by substitution:
$$ \pi(3)^4\div4-\pi(0)^4\div4$$

So this brings us to the answer for the area in terms of $\pi$:
$(81\div4)\pi$

## Is this the correct answer?

Comment: The integral looks wrong, to get the volume you need the area of a circular slice, which would be $\pi r^2 = \pi x^4$ I think.

Comment: Was your intention to integrate discs or cylindrical shells? It looks like you may be getting the two mixed up.

Comment: Well, from what I have been told, it is best to use the shell method for y-axis volume. So, yes, that's what I am trying to do.